# objc_msgSend appWillTerminate

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, crashlytics

Can anyone please explain the crashlog?
I am not getting that for which notification this crash is appearing.

```
> Crashed: com.apple.main-thread EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at
> 0x714e79b2  raw 0 libobjc.A.dylib  objc_msgSend + 5 appWillTerminate:
> 1 CoreFoundation  
> __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12 2 CoreFoundation  
> _CFXNotificationPost + 1784 3 Foundation  
> -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 72 4 Foundation   
> -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:] + 30 5 UIKit 
> -[UIApplication _terminateWithStatus:] + 218 6 UIKit  
> -[UIApplication _handleApplicationDectivationWithScene:shouldForceExit:transitionContext:completion:]
> + 2518 7 UIKit    
> -[UIApplication workspaceShouldExit:] + 140 8 FrontBoardServices  
> __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 12 9   CoreFoundation  
> __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12 15   UIKit    UIApplicationMain + 1440 16 Meeting     main.m line 13 main
```

Comment: Could you share your notification code?

Comment: There is a lot of notification , for which notification i have to share?

Comment: Did try adding Exception Breakpoint?

Comment: I tried but application stopped at main.m.

Comment: I believe you could try a symbolic breakpoint on postNotificationName if you want to discover which.  It *might* work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that one of your notification is sent while your app is suspended, probably one that has some UI duty in the callback.